# Change oracle display message

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have written a procedure to check the file exists in the oracle directory. it is working fine. On screen i am printing message if file not exists in path, by using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE('MESSAGE HERE');` but after displaying message oracle printing default statement **PL/SQL Procedure successfully completed**. I don't want to display this on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To suppress the message in sql*plus of successfully completed procedure use the following command.

```
set feedback off
```