# Calling SQL*Plus commands in PL/SQL block

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is there any way to set the serveroutput on/off using pl/sql procedures/packages. I want to do some changes in displaying of my data on SQL*PLUS screen. like [for my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278889/change-oracle-display-message)

Comment: `"want to do some changes in"` can you elaborate `"some"`?

Comment: No you cannot use sql*plus commands inside PL/SQL block. Please give more information about what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call SQL*Plus commands (which run only on the client) from PL/SQL (which runs only on the server).

In the particular case where you simply want to enable and disable message output, however, you can call the PL/SQL procedures [`dbms_output.disable`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i999434) and [`dbms_output.enable`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i999293).

If you are depending on the data being written via `dbms_output` to be displayed to a human user, however, you are almost certainly doing something wrong.  Production processes should be writing important data to some other location (i.e. a table somewhere), not writing to `dbms_output` and hoping that the client application happens to be configured to display the data.

Comment: I am writing number of records processed data into SQL*PLUS screen, Using **dbms_output.putline** . And i am writting all exceptions and data in a file. If oracle server has set serveroutput off then i want to make it on. And if any error occurred while processing files(i am checking existence of file and then returning a message to console), as mentioned in previous post i want to set feedback off.

Comment: @mallikarjun - It doesn't make sense for a production process to write the number of rows processed to the `dbms_output` buffer. You would write that sort of thing to a table that tracks each execution of your extract. As I said in my answer, you can enable and disable `dbms_output` from PL/SQL.  You cannot `set feedback off` from PL/SQL since that is a client-side setting. And your server-side PL/SQL cannot force the client application to have enabled `serveroutput`.